# Remove :active state of dom element in an UIWebView on an iPad

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, uiwebview

I have several Buttons (li-Tags with background images). I can switch the background images depending on the ":active" pseudo-class. It is added on touchStart and removed on touchEnd by the UiWebView. All good. But when I use a dialog screen and return from it the ":active" status is still present on the button which called the dialog. Another touch gets rid of it but still it's annoying. How can I remove it?

I tried stuff like

```
$(".theButton").removeClass("active");
$(".theButton").removeClass(":active");
$(".theButton").blur();
```

But I am more poking around than having a real plan. Is there a way to remove the active state via JavaScript?

Thank you very much

*edit*

I use [FastclickJS](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to prevent ghostClicks. It may be part of the problem.

Comment: As I don't use jQuery Mobile there is no "ui-btn-active" class. Trying to remove a "normal" active class failed as stated above. Thx for your comment nonetheless :)

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle showing your problem

Comment: No need to delete your comment. I am unable to reproduce the error using jfiddle. I just realized I am using fastclick.js to prevent ghostclicks. see: http://jsfiddle.net/MZGgy/4/

Answer (score 1):

For the time being I use a "real" CSS Class for changing the background and set the class via jQuery. That way I can enable and disable the class.

CSS:

```
.someButton.active {
someStyle;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.removeButton').addClass("active");

$('.removeButton').removeClass("active");
```